# Missing Instagram Caption in iOS 9 app

Tags: ios, swift, instagram

I have done the below code to post an Image and a Text on Instagram

```
let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: writePath)
self.documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: fileURL)
self.documentController.delegate = self
self.documentController.UTI = "com.instagram.exclusivegram"//"com.instagram.photo"
self.documentController.annotation =  NSDictionary(object: strTitle as String, forKey: "InstagramCaption")
self.documentController.presentOpenInMenuFromRect(self.view.frame, inView: self.view, animated: true)
```

It's working fine in iOS 8.3 but the Caption is missing in iOS 9.
Why is that and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, and I have found out that it has been removed by Instagram on earlier August, 2015.

Instagram blog http://developers.instagram.com/post/125972775561/removing-pre-filled-captions-from-mobile-sharing

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. At that time the caption was working for iOS 8 and earlier devices but not on iOS 9. And now all is gone .. :(

Comment: Yeah, both Facebook and Instagram have depreciated the pre-filled caption. :/

Answer (score 2):

Just found out that Instagram removed this function in its new version

https://www.apichangelog.com/changes/c6542ec9-6e02-4352-8db4-6481a8af4039

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure since I don't have a sample project to try, but is there a particular reason not to use Swift dictionary instead of NSDictionary?

```
self.documentController.annotation = ["InstagramCaption": strTitle]
```

It'd be nice if you could provide a sample project. Also, keep in mind that Swift 2 is still in beta, so is iOS 9. I found a few bug in OS X El Capitan with Swift 2 recently that code works on Yosemite does not work the as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did the same in a different way

 self.documentController.annotation =  NSDictionary(object: strTitle as String, forKey: "InstagramCaption")

Comment: It'd be really help if you have a sample project that can reproduce the problem, otherwise only limited users that use the same api as you can help. :)

Comment: here's the link for a sample https://www.dropbox.com/s/d0xvpfla3ru2zly/SampleInstagram.zip?dl=0

Hope, you'll give a solution

Comment: I don't think there's a problem in those code as far as I can see. I tested it in the simulator and `self.documentController.annotation` did capture the value from the setter. (Tested in Xcode 7 + iOS 9 SDK) There should be other reasons that caused the issue, e.g. Instagram isn't 100% compatible with iOS 9 beta or some other parts of your code caused it.

Comment: I also have the same issue on iOS8.4.

Comment: any solution to this? InstagramCaption stopped working in iOS8.4

Answer (score 0):

If you are us iOS Hooks then it  will stop accepting captions passed by third party apps. Existing mobile apps that utilize pre-filled captions will continue to be able to use this flow to share media through the Instagram apps, but now Instagram will ignore the caption text. To create a caption for a photo or video shared by a third party app, users will have to enter a caption manually, the same way they already do when sharing content using the Instagram native apps.

Thanks.